# In Mac OS how can I find and move a large list of files from one folder to another?

Tags: macos, file-management

I have a list of about 1,200 files that are stored in a folder on my hard drive (total files in that folder is about 1,900 files). Is there a way (maybe using Terminal) to search for those 1,200 files and move them to a new folder on my hard drive?

Comment: Probably belongs on Think Different, but since that's not a flag option, Super User it is...

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10784/how-can-i-move-multiple-files-at-once

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not seeing anything in that thread about how to tell the system only to move certain files within the folder. I have to move a 1,200 out of the 1,900 files. I have a list of the file names I need to move. How can I do that via Terminal?